# react I want to hide the div tag when the animation is over

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm using framer-motion for animation.
When the animation pageVariants finishes, I want to hide the div tag used for the animation.
Currently, when the animation is finished, the div tags are moved to the bottom of the screen so that the user can scroll vertically. I would like to make it so that users cannot scroll vertically after the animation ends.
Is there any way to detect when the animation is finished?

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

const Home: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const ease = [0.43, 0.13, 0.23, 0.96];

  const pageVariants = {
    initial: {
      y: '0',
      transition: { ease, duration: 10, delay: 0.8 },
    },
    animate: {
      y: '100%',
      transition: { ease, duration: 10 },
      transitionEnd: { display: "none",},
    },
    exit: {
      y: '0',
      opacity: 0,
      transition: { ease, duration: 10, delay: 0.8 },
    },
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr auto' }}>
        <div className="bg-red-100 h-screen">box</div>
        <div className="bg-blue-100 w-96">box2</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: '300px',
          position: 'absolute',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          marginRight: 'auto',
          bottom: 0,
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <img src="profile.svg" />
          <p>hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <motion.div
        className="h-screen bg-white absolute z-50 w-full -top-0"
        variants={pageVariants}
      ></motion.div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation of framer-motion a [transitionEnd](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/component/#supported-values) attribute is described. If you set it to your motion div like this, it should disappear at the end of the animation:

```
<motion.div
        className="h-screen bg-white absolute z-50 w-full -top-0"
        variants={pageVariants}
        animate={{
          transitionEnd: {
            display: "none",
          },
        }}
      >
</motion.div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added transitionEnd to animate in pageVariants. However, I can only scroll for a moment.

Comment: If you could provide me a working example e.g. with https://stackblitz.com/, I can check why you cant scroll anymore. But without visually seeing what it is exactly you want to achieve, I doubt I can help. If display:none is not suitable you can of course also change it with other css-styles.

Comment: It was difficult to build my environment on stackblitz.com and it didn't work.
I added display:none, but I can scroll for a moment after the animation is over.
The code is up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Reference: [onAnimationComplete](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/###onanimationcomplete)

```
const [hideAnimationTag, setHideAnimationTag] = useState(false)

{!hideAnimationTag && <motion.div
   className="h-screen bg-white absolute z-50 w-full -top-0"
   variants={pageVariants}
   onAnimationComplete={() => {
    setHideAnimationTag(true)
  }}
/>}
```